# Is there a VI command that will generically insert a colon in the second field of every line

Tags: string, vi

This is an example of the beginning of each line in a file:
Line 1: `20210112 2039:37.669`
Line 2: `20210112 2040:15.701`
Line 3: `20210112 2041:23.223`

I want the second field's `HHMM` to be in the format `HH:MM`
Line 1: `20210112 20:39:37.669`
Line 2: `20210112 20:40:15.701`
Line 3: `20210112 20:41:23.223`

I know how to do this using three string substitution commands but I am hoping that there is a single VI command that will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`:%s/.........../&:/<Enter>`

Commentary: This will insert a colon into column 12 (after the 11 character) and shift the remaining characters to the right by one character.

```
:       # Enter vi command line
%s      # Prepare to make a global substitution
/       # begin the pattern match
.       # Match any single character. In this case you want to match the first 11 characters. So provide 11 periods
 /      # End your pattern match
&:      # Perform action of inserting a colon
/       # Terminate the replacement character set
<Enter> # Execute your command by pressing the Enter key
```